# Android TalkBack only cycles through on screen content in browser

Tags: android, angular, accessibility, talkback

I am working on an Angular 2 web app and testing for Accessibility issues on Android with TalkBack screen reader.

Swiping right through the main content blocks works as expected until I get to the bottom of the screen.  When I navigate to the next block in the same way (swiping right) instead of moving on to the next content block which is off screen below and then scrolling down, the screen reader starts again at the top.

Other websites do not have this issue with TalkBack when navigating to content off screen.  I tried to add tabindex="0" to the offscreen content just to experiment but that had no observable effect.

Anyone run into this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome @ChrisCM

Answer (score 0):

the same issue I was facing in android Samsung note 5 and note 9 but it is working fine for other phone so i have figured out that there is talkback accessibility app i have to install from google play store ( https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.marvin.talkback&hl=en_IN ) and then it works fine.